# Error: Non-base58 character

Tags: anchor, cli, devnet, error, base58

I upload the program to the network, but when interacting it issues this error

```
Error: Non-base58 character    
at Object.decode (/mnt/c/Users/Mateo/block3/node_modules/base-x/src/index.js:111:11)
        at new PublicKey (/mnt/c/Users/Mateo/block3/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/publickey.ts:63:30)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/c/Users/Mateo/block3/tests/Accounts.ts:6:30)
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
        at Module.m._compile (/mnt/c/Users/Mateo/block3/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:439:23)
        at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
        at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/mnt/c/Users/Mateo/block3/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:442:12)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
        at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
        at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:101:18)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/c/Users/Mateo/block3/tests/MainAccount.ts:3:1)
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
        at Module.m._compile (/mnt/c/Users/Mateo/block3/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:439:23)
        at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
        at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/mnt/c/Users/Mateo/block3/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:442:12)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
        at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
        at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:101:18)
        at Object.exports.requireOrImport (/mnt/c/Users/Mateo/block3/node_modules/mocha/lib/nodejs/esm-utils.js:60:20)
        at Object.exports.loadFilesAsync (/mnt/c/Users/Mateo/block3/node_modules/mocha/lib/nodejs/esm-utils.js:103:20)
        at singleRun (/mnt/c/Users/Mateo/block3/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run-helpers.js:125:3)
        at Object.exports.handler (/mnt/c/Users/Mateo/block3/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run.js:374:5)
    error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: can you be more clear with what you mean by "when interacting"

Answer (score 2):

PROBLEM SOLVED

My part on the client side was perfect. The thing that caused the error was an account (not used by the instruction) that will be used to do fetch later. Therefore, if you see this error, `check if you are writing the correct pubkey`